# Pandas cannot convert multiple dtypes to date

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

I have a Pandas dataframe with multiple date columns but the dtypes are of multiple data types. Is there a way to concurrently convert each column into the same date format

| dtype | column |
| --- | --- |
| float64 | BirthDate |
| float64 | HireDate |
| int64 | AnniversaryDate |
| object | ReportDate |

**Approach A:**

```
for col in df:
  if ('date' in col) or ('Date' in col):
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col]).dt.date
```

**Result:**

```
   2210 try:
-> 2211     values, tz_parsed = conversion.datetime_to_datetime64(data.ravel("K"))
   2212     # If tzaware, these values represent unix timestamps, so we
   2213     #  return them as i8 to distinguish from wall times
```

**Approach B:**

```
for col in df:
  if ('date' in col) or ('Date' in col):
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col], errors='coerce').dt.date
```

**Result:**

| dtype | column |
| --- | --- |
| object | BirthDate |
| datetime64[ns] | HireDate |
| object | AnniversaryDate |
| datetime64[ns] | ReportDate |

What I thought was originally working is actually rendering all dates to 1/1/1970 aka the Unix epoch, so I am stuck wondering whether each dtype requires its own conversion, whether a Try/Catch is a more appropriate solution, or something else.

Comment: You should provide an example of the dataframe or at least all the possible date/datetime format you expect to have.

Comment: this is pretty extensively covered in the documentation. Check the `format` and `unit` parameters https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html